# Unable to use pandas excel writer with zipline dataframe?

Tags: finance, zipline, quantopian

I'm trying to write a dataframe (from zipline pickle) to excel, but so far it's not working as usual (for dataframes). Suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
```

`backtest_df.to_excel(writer,'sheet1')`

`writer.save()`

With the following error:

KeyError: class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'

Comment: could you post an example of the dataframe? Also, did you try changing it to a pandas df before calling writer on it?

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading your `openpyxl` package to 2.5.3 version.

I had the same error using 2.5.6 version of `openpyxl` and trying to save a pandas `DataFrame` with a `DatetimeIndex`. Downgrading it to 2.5.3 solved it for me.